# Heterogeneous content on a page

Tags: cms

I am a newbie but I have experience with other cms systems. Let's say we have a page called Paper Airplane Instrucutions and my client wants to add some text, a picture, some more text, and then a photo gallery on the page. Then we create another page called Paper Hat Instructions and the client wants to add just text and a video.

I want both pages to use the same template. But I want my client to easily add these different types of content using either posts with custom post types or some other method.

In my cms, I created custom components, a text component, a video component, a gallery component, that clients can add and configure and stack on top of each other like legos to construct a web page with these different content blocks. They can reorder the blocks if they want. Then they can create another page and add blocks to that page but perhaps in a different order.

Can someone advise me on a plugin or strategy to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom post type for Paper Airplane Instructions and one for Paper Hat Instructions and just use the same template by duplicating it for each one. There are plugins that do this ( like custom post type UI) but it is way better to learn the code and just add it to your functions.php.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Post_Types

The template hierarchy is essential reading, http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Posts and pages come with what your asking for by default ( text + media (vid/photo/gallery/etc) but they can be extended with Custom fields ( http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields ) and by defining custom widget "areas", or just writing whatever php/html/css/etc in the customized template file.